# how to have relations many to many in mongodbmo

Tags: mongodb

I have just started learning  MongoDB. 
Can somebody please give something about how to implement this example with mongodb?

the example

```
# Here are my categories
> hmset category:1 name cinema  ... more fields ...
> hmset category:2 name music   ... more fields ...
> hmset category:3 name sports  ... more fields ...
> hmset category:4 name nature  ... more fields ...

# Here are my users
> hmset user:1 name Jack   ... more fields ...
> hmset user:2 name John   ... more fields ...
> hmset user:3 name Julia  ... more fields ...

# Let's establish the many-to-many relationship
# Jack likes cinema and sports
# John likes music and nature
# Julia likes cinema, music and nature

# For each category, we keep a set of reference on the users
> sadd category:1:users 1 3
> sadd category:2:users 2 3
> sadd category:3:users 1
> sadd category:4:users 2 3

# For each user, we keep a set of reference on the categories
> sadd user:1:categories 1 3
> sadd user:2:categories 2 4
> sadd user:3:categories 1 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, you have the option of prejoining the data, so you could put the documents as :

```
user : "John",
categories : ["music", "nature"]
```

There's also an option to put references (more like RDBMS):

```
user : "John",
categories : [    ObjectId("1e222222222"),
                  ObjectId("2e333333") ]
```

This will basically depend on your data access pattern. So, if you basically just retrieve categories associated with a user then the first case should be fine else you could consider the second case of having different collections for users and categories and then referencing them which would come out something like below, for example:

```
var category = { _id: "music"
            , name: "Musical Category"
            , users: ["jack", "julia", "john"] }
var user = { _id: "jack", name: "Jack", categories: ["music"]}
db.categories.save(category)
db.users.save(user)

db.categories.find({_id: {$in: user.categories}}) // categories for user
db.users.find({_id: {$in: category.users}}) // users for category
```

But I have just touched the topic of schema design. You would have to analyze your cardinality and data access patterns to arrive a solid design.
Below posts from Mongo gives really good explanation with examples:
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

From the manual : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/